# Protocol Handler on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have this .desktop file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Tagger
Comment=Read and create QR code and barcode tags
Exec=/usr/share/tagger-app/tagger %U
Icon=/usr/share/tagger-app/graphics/tagger.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-Ubuntu-Touch=true
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/yada
```

I know it's being read because the icon appears.

I visit the link yada:// in the standard browser app and it says "network error" and does not attempt to open the application.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [URL Dispatcher](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/platform/guides/url-dispatcher-guide/). I don't know if it will work typing the scheme directly into the browser's location bar, but it should work if you click a link with that scheme or if another app tries to open a URL with that scheme.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I took the advice from the provided tutorial and tested it from the browser with a link. No workie. Immediately, I blamed myself so I looked at url-dispatcher files and saw album:// and music:// handlers. So I made links and clicked those in the browser and they didn't work either.

However, I did open the news app and tapped some http:// links. This launches the browser app.

Perhaps the browser app is the only app that gobbles up every tap event?